# Size of object array is being added to the localstorage not the array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const arr = {
      i: id,
      quant: quantity,
    };
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('quantityData') === true) {**checking if the local storage has the 'quantityData' property already**
      if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('quantityData').length !== 0)) {
        const getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('quantityData'));
        console.log(getData);
        const val = getData.find(x => x.i === id);**checking if array has the object with particular id property**
        if (val) {**if yes then I will update the quant property of that object with current quantity(state variable)**
          getData.forEach(x => {
            if (x.i === id) {
              x.quant = quantity;
              localStorage.setItem('quantityData', JSON.stringify(getData));
            }
          });
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem(
            'quantityData',
            JSON.stringify(getData.push(arr))**If I dont find the element then I will just push the new element in the quantity Data array
          );
        }
      }
    } else {
      const a = [];
      a.push(arr);
      localStorage.setItem('quantityData', JSON.stringify(a));**Here when I am uploading the array to the local storage I am getting the size of array in the local storage instaed of the object array**
    }
  }, [quantity]);
```

When I am Uploading the data to the localStorage I am getting the size of object array that I have created instead of the array with data object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript array function push returns the new length of the array. You need to push and setItem like belows.

```
getData.push(arr)
localStorage.setItem(
    'quantityData',
    JSON.stringify(getData)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make your `const a` an object instead of an array it should return properly